# Io Language fails to build: Foundation/Foundation.h: No such file or directory

Tags: compiler-construction, installation, iolanguage

I'm trying to build that Io language from source on Ubuntu 10.10 and not having a great deal of success.

I cloned the repo, I navigated to the build/ directory, I executed "cmake ..", it seemed to go okay, I executed "sudo make install" and it fails with this message:

```
[ 65%] Building CXX object addons/ObjcBridge/CMakeFiles/IoObjcBridge.dir/source/Io2Objc.m.o
/home/sam/Dropbox/programs/io/addons/ObjcBridge/source/Io2Objc.m:5: fatal error: Foundation/Foundation.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [addons/ObjcBridge/CMakeFiles/IoObjcBridge.dir/source/Io2Objc.m.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [addons/ObjcBridge/CMakeFiles/IoObjcBridge.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I've been Googling and trying things for a few hours with no luck. Apparently this is something to do with the Objective C compiler and I've tried installing gnustep (admittedly with no idea what I was doing) to no avail.

If you need any more detail please ask :)

Thanks in advance,

Sam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building https://github.com/stevedekorte/io on non-Darwin platforms (such as Ubuntu) no longer works since commit 5ee63f37d5952cc0a7a025ac3e6d518a7b78d1f4 .

A pull request, https://github.com/stevedekorte/io/pull/123 , contains a fix this.

So you can either wait until a fix is applied to the main repo or just clone git://github.com/jeremytregunna/io.git .

```
git clone git://github.com/jeremytregunna/io.git
cd io
./build.sh
sudo ./build.sh install
sudo ldconfig
io
```

Comment: The aforementioned pull request has now been pulled into the main line: https://github.com/stevedekorte/io/pull/123